# Is a manifold-with-boundary with given interior and non-empty boundary essentially unique?

Tags: manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, compact-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact connected manifold-with-boundary such that $\circ M \neq \emptyset$, where $\circ M$ is the boundary of $M$. Let $N$ be a compact connected manifold-with-boundary such that $\circ N \neq \emptyset$ and $\bullet M \approx \bullet N$, where $\bullet M$ denotes the interior of $M$ and $\approx$ denotes homeomorphic. Does it necessarily hold that $N \approx M$?

EDIT: Since there were no replies here, I asked the same question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/328149/32487). The surprising answer is no.